# Problems with my program deleting objects from pointer list and adding to pointerlist

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I was wondering could someone help me complete my program, I am having some issues with my dragon.cpp file, it seems I can't seem to create dragons of different types.

I am still new to C++ and me dunno how to solve these errors

### UPDATE

I deleted the 2nd constructor from the dragon.cpp now i get new errors. Also i added a virtual deconstructor into the header file for class Dragon.

error

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class DragonCave const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVDragonCave@@@Z) referenced in function _main  main.obj    1   
Error   LNK1120 5 unresolved externals  Dragon.exe  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __thiscall Dragon::getName(void)const " (?getName@Dragon@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main   main.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall DragonCave::accommodateDragon(class Dragon *)" (?accommodateDragon@DragonCave@@QAEXPAVDragon@@@Z) referenced in function _main  main.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall DragonCave::evictDragon(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?evictDragon@DragonCave@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main        main.obj    1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall DragonCave::DragonCave(void)" (??0DragonCave@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   main.obj    1
```

my main.cpp

```
https://pastebin.com/dKwuVPn7
```

my dragon.hpp

```
https://pastebin.com/cbJ2Z80D
```

my dragon.cpp

```
#include "dragon.hpp"
 
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
 
/* Dragon class functions here*/
Dragon::Dragon(std::string const& name, size_t age, size_t size) {}
/* DragonCave class functions here*/
DragonCave::DragonCave() {
 
    std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    for (auto i : d.dragons) {
        Dragon *c = i->clone();
        dragons.push_back(c);
    }
}
 
// Made for you, as it uses a tiny bit of dynamic memory here! You will see more of this in the next round.
DragonCave::~DragonCave()
{
    for (std::list<Dragon*>::iterator it = dragons.begin(); it != dragons.end(); it++)
        delete *it;
}
 
/* ChineseDragon class functions */
//Constructor here
 
ChineseDragon::ChineseDragon(std::string const& name, size_t age, size_t size) : Dragon(name, age, size) { }
 
void ChineseDragon::eat(std::list<Food>& food)
{
    for (std::list<Food>::iterator it = food.begin(); it != food.end();)
        if (it->type == PeopleFood)
        {
            std::cout << "Chinese dragon ate: " << it->name << std::endl;
            it = food.erase(it);
            size++;
        }
        else it++;
 
}
 
void ChineseDragon::hoard(std::list<Treasure>& treasures)
{
    for (std::list<Treasure>::iterator it = treasures.begin(); it != treasures.end();)
        if (it->type == Potions)
        {
            std::cout << "Chinese dragon received: " << it->name << std::endl;
            this->treasures.push_back(*it);
            it = treasures.erase(it);
        }
        else it++;
 
 
}
 
 
FantasyDragon::FantasyDragon(std::string const& name, size_t age, size_t size) : Dragon(name, age, size) { }
 
void FantasyDragon::eat(std::list<Food>& food)
{
    for (std::list<Food>::iterator it = food.begin(); it != food.end();)
        if (it->type == PeopleFood | People)
        {
            std::cout << "Fantasy dragon ate: " << it->name << std::endl;
            it = food.erase(it);
            size++;
        }
        else it++;
 
 
}
 
void FantasyDragon::hoard(std::list<Treasure>& treasures)
{
 
    for (std::list<Treasure>::iterator it = treasures.begin(); it != treasures.end();)
        if (it->type == Potions)
        {
            std::cout << "Fantasy dragon received: " << it->name << std::endl;
            this->treasures.push_back(*it);
            it = treasures.erase(it);
        }
        else it++;
 
}
 
 
/* MagicDragon class functions */
MagicDragon::MagicDragon(std::string const& name, size_t age, size_t size) : Dragon(name, age, size) { }
 
void MagicDragon::eat(std::list<Food>& food)
{
    for (std::list<Food>::iterator it = food.begin(); it != food.end();)
        if (it->type == Herbs)
        {
            std::cout << "Magic dragon ate: " << it->name << std::endl;
            it = food.erase(it);
            size++;
        }
        else it++;
}
 
void MagicDragon::hoard(std::list<Treasure>& treasures)
{
    for (std::list<Treasure>::iterator it = treasures.begin(); it != treasures.end();)
        if (it->type == Potions)
        {
            std::cout << "Magic dragon received: " << it->name << std::endl;
            this->treasures.push_back(*it);
            it = treasures.erase(it);
        }
        else it++;
}
```

Comment: You implemented your `Dragon` constructor in both the header and the source file. You should only do it in one or the other.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and post all the relevant code directly into the question. As it is there is a lot of unnecessary code in the one file you provided.

Comment: @Galik thanks for noticing, now i get new errors, i have updated the question.

Comment: That's probably a list of functions you didn't write implementations for - or you gave them the wrong types of parameters maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Those errors tell you that some of your functions lack an implementation. Specifically `operator<<(std::ostream& os, DragonCave const& cave)`, `Dragon::getName`, `DragonCave::accommodateDragon` and `DragonCave::evictDragon` are declared but never defined.

The last error refers to `DragonCave::DragonCave()` which, according to the code you posted, is in fact defined. However it seems to have been a copy constructor once, and there is a variable `d` that appears out of nowhere. I suspect the error has something to do with this.